# How can I remove specific strings from a sentence using Regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this following sentence: `Crazy Fredrick bought many very exquisite opal jewels.`
and I need to use regex in the following format:

```
Crazy Fredrick bought many very exquisite opal jewels.".replace(/regex goes here/gi,"")
```

to get the following result: `Crazy bought very opal jewels.`
So how can i use regex to query out those specific parts of the sentence?

Comment: `.replace(/(Fredrick|many|exquisite)/gi,"")`

Comment: Thank you, i didnt even think about the '|'
that should have been obvious haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.replace(/(Fredrick|many|exquisite)/gi,"")
```